# Can't replace a string with multiple escape characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with the `replace()` method. I want to replace some part of a string, and the part which I want to replace consist of multiple escape characters. It looks like something like this;

```
['<div class=\"content\">rn
```

To remove it, I have a block of code;

```
garbage_text = "[\'<div class=\\\"content\\\">rn    "
entry = entry.replace(garbage_text,"")
```

However, it does not work. Anything is removed from my complete string. Can anybody point out where exactly I am thinking wrong about it? Thanks in advance.

**Addition:**

The complete string looks like this;

```
"['<div class=\"content\">rn    gitar calmak icin kullanilan minik plastik garip nesne.rn  </div>']"
```

Comment: What's with the extra white space at the end of `garbage_text`?

Comment: What do you mean? Removing the extra space at the end of `garbage_text` I see that the text you provided is replaced.

Comment: @busybear, I also want to remove that white space from my complete string

Comment: Please check the addition in my question.

Comment: Are you sure the backslashes before the dbl quotes are actually in the string and not just an artifact of how you are viewing it?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Actually I am scraping this strings from a web page and then storing them into a json file. When I open json file and check, I can see that the backslashes are staying there.

Comment: If that is the case then it should work: https://ideone.com/KGrRNV

Comment: Your example works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the triple quote format for your replacement string so that you don't have to bother with escaping at all:

```
garbage_text = """['<div class="content">rn    """
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your 'entry' is not formatted correctly?

With an extra variable 'text', the following worked in Python 3.6.7:

```
>>> garbage_text
'[\'<div class=\\\'content\'\\">rn     '
>>> text
'[\'<div class=\\\'content\'\\">rn     And then there were none'
>>> entry = text.replace(garbage_text, "")
>>> entry
'And then there were none'
```